# SSAS Date dimension schema generation fails

Tags: date, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

I am following the standard steps to create date dimension in SSAS [here](http://tavislovell.com/how-to-auto-generate-a-time-dimension/)-

The generate schema option fails! this is the message from schema generation wizard

> create failed for table myusername.dimdate

I think the problem is that the table should be created for a different schema. If below is the selected option for schema generation -

```
Subject Area
    Data source view: ABC PROJ
    **Schema: ABC_PROJ(WXY1230)**

Data will be preserved
Time table will be populated
```

Shouldn't the Dimdate table be created **ABC_PROF(WXY1230).Dimdate** and **not under myusername.DimDate**?

Any idea what could be missing? I have been struggling with this for hours now. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is an unfortunate bug in the SSAS generated date dimension. When you generate the dimension you are using your Windows credentials and SSAS uses the default schema for the user context it was provided. I believe your user has a default schema of myusername on that database, which is what is causing the date dimesion to be created there.

If you create the dimension, you have the option to generate the schema now or generate it later. If you choose to generate it later and go through the Schema Generation Wizard, you eventually see a screen that shows the Owning Schema. 
[image]. There is no mechanism to change it even though you can see it (At least not in SSDT. I don't have BIDS on any of my machines). You are [not the only person to run into this issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f8acafa6-49ff-44ac-9aad-c9411a8b5f16/is-it-possible-to-change-the-owning-schema-when-generating-datetime-dimensions-in-the-datasource?forum=sqlanalysisservices).

So you have a few options as a workaround:

1. Use a different account that has a default schema that is the correct schema where you want to place your date table.
2. Create the table under your default user and populate it. Then alter the table in SQL Server to move it to the correct schema. Then update your DSV.
3. Don't use SSAS to generate your date dimension. There are plenty of scripts out there that create great date dimensions. [Here's an example.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647950/Create-and-Populate-Date-Dimension-for-Data-Wareho) This means you will need to create the dimension and build the hierarchy yourself, but it's not that much work compared to the time you've spent trying to fix this issue.